# ASP.NET MVC not saving to database when I set other action name in BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Everything is ok when I don't have other action name in `beginform`, the values are saved to the database:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // some textboxes
}
```

But I want to create a new view, sort of like Reservation Confirmed type, but when I try to use the new action name, the data doesn't get saved.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Final", "Reservations"))
{
    // some textboxes
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your controller code?

Comment: Do you have any error?And can your share your action code?

Comment: Thank you guys, I forgot the controller....
I`m a begginer at MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, i just changed the return to the Post Action in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,Ime,Prezime,Denovi,Lica,Cena,Telefon,DataNaPristignuvanje,DataNaZaminuvanje,VremeRezervacija")] Reservation reservation)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Final");//initially was Index
            }

            return View(reservation);
        }
```